# Regex option OR match

Tags: regex

Is there a way to do optional OR ?. I want to match on these interfaces as part of group1

```
interface GigabitEthernet3/11
interface GigabitEthernet2/2
interface GigabitEthernet2/3

text is here:

interface GigabitEthernet2/1
 description test
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 202
 no logging event link-status
 no logging event power-inline-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/4
 description User
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport mode access
 no logging event link-status
 no logging event power-inline-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/4
 description User
 switchport access vlan 102
 no logging event link-status
 no logging event power-inline-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/11
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 102,202
 switchport trunk native vlan 102
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 202
 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/2
 description User
 switchport mode access
 no logging event link-status
 no logging event power-inline-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/3
 switchport voice vlan 202
 no logging event link-status
 no logging event power-inline-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree guard root
!
```

My regex expression:

```js
(interface [A-Za-z]+\d\/\S+)\n(?:^\s.*|\n)*(switchport access vlan\s(\d+))|(switchport mode access)|(switchport voice vlan.*)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JELspP/1)

Comment: What exactly do you want as a match in group 1? What is the tool or language?

Comment: python is the language. checkout this regex https://regex101.com/r/JELspP/1

Need to capture these interfaces in group 1 as well as the ones mentioned in the group if they exists. 

interface GigabitEthernet3/11
interface GigabitEthernet2/2
interface GigabitEthernet2/3

Comment: If you want the interface with all the possible "switchport" values for that interface in group 1, I don't think that is possible with a regex as you can not skip matching `description test` or `description User` for example. What you could do is match the whole interface part, and use a second pattern to match the specific "switchport" parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a way to get all the 'switchports' captured
in a single interface record, the below just adds the different ones inside
an alternation (OR as you said).

Just add more or switchport items as needed.
The below happens to get all the relevant items in an *out-of-order* way
that will also take into account any interleaving if it occurs.

```
(?im)^(interface[ ][A-Za-z\d]+\/\S+)(?:\s*(?:^(?!(?:interface|!)).*\s+)*?[ \t]+(?:(switchport[ \t]+access[ \t]+vlan[ \t]+(\d+))|(switchport[ \t]+voice[ \t]+vlan)|(switchport[ \t]+mode[ \t]+access)).*)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/rjzC4y/1

```
 (?im)
 ^ 
 ( interface [ ] [A-Za-z\d]+ \/ \S+ )                  # (1)
 (?:
    \s* 
    (?:
       ^ 
       (?!
          (?: interface | ! )
       )
       .* \s+ 
    )*?
    [ \t]+ 
    (?:
       (                                               # (2 start)
          switchport [ \t]+ access [ \t]+ vlan [ \t]+ 
          ( \d+ )                                      # (3)
       )                                               # (2 end)
     | ( switchport [ \t]+ voice [ \t]+ vlan )         # (4)
     | ( switchport [ \t]+ mode [ \t]+ access )        # (5)
       
       # Add more switchport types here
       
    )
    .* 
 )*
```